# Xamarin Bluetooth and BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, polly

I've read that people recommend putting a call to connect to a device via BlueTooth on Xamarin's main UI thread like so:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
  await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(targetDevice, new Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.ConnectParameters(), token);
});
```

However, I'd like to be proactive and put a retry policy around that using Polly:

```
retryPolicy = Policy
              .Handle<Exception>()
              .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                new[]{
                   TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                   TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                   TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) },
               (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) => {
                  Console.WriteLine("Exception inside polly: " + result.ToString());
               });
```

Is it better to execute the policy inside the BeginInvokeOnMainThread like this:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
  await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => {
    await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(targetDevice, new Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.ConnectParameters(), token);
  });
});
```

Or will we see better results if we place a synchronous retry policy around the BeginInvokeOnMainThread:

```
Polly.Policy.Handle<Exception>().Retry(3).Execute(() => {
  Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
    await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(targetDevice, new Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.ConnectParameters(), token);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am not familar with Polly, but `Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` used for updating UI when get the data in the child thread or sync.  if you want to update UI in xamarin forms application, your application need to running in the main thread.

Comment: I understand the concepts behind the BeginInvokeOnMainThread functionality and when to use it.  In fact, it is actually recommended to use it for Bluetooth calls specifically because Android can have problems writing multiple times to the bluetooth adapter if they are not in a concurrent queue.  Hence the usage of putting the calls on the UI thread.

Comment: @Josh Could you please elaborate on "better results"? Have you done any measurement so far?

Comment: @PeterCsala What I'm trying to figure out is if it is more performant to put the retries directly on the UI thread or if placing the retries on a background thread is more performant.  Sometimes, connections can cause errors or the initial BLE connection didn't go through, hence the Polly retry.

Comment: @Josh Async retries will only release the UI thread between attempts if you have defined delay /  penalty. In that case it will use `await Task.Delay.(...);`